# Ways to update dbfirst Entity Framework model at runtime

Tags: c#

I would like to ask if it is possible to update database model (eg. columns) at runtime?

I've learned about Entity Framework (had to use database-first approach in my case) or Linq-to-SQL, but when database table changes, I have to update application's model manually.

In my application I would like to use MVVM pattern, so there must be a model class, which reflects a database table. As far as I know I can't add property to a class at runtime.

Here's example scenario:

1. Database table has 3 columns: col1, col2, col3
2. Model class has 3 properties: col1, col2, col3
3. Using Entity Framework I can get data from the database easily and then bind that data to controls eg. DataGrid
4. Application user is able to add new column to database
5. And there is a problem. I can't find any way to refresh model and then bind to DataGrid.

Question: is there any tools to help me solving problem from point 5 ?

Comment: i believe what you are looking for is EF migrations?

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with the architecture. I would never allow a user to add new columns to the database. What problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: @phuzi Application has to be flexible for the user. Imagine situation where software developer is on vacations. Application is blocked for that period of time, because there is noone to migrate model to database.

Comment: Typically I have seen such dynamic fields to be implemented in a seperate table or two as rows - not by modifying the application. You would then have a property such as `IList<CustomColumn> userColumns` on the model

Comment: I would suggest that the application needs to be able to handle these custom columns without modifying the code There is likely to be a performance penalty in doing so, but you can't have it both ways.

Comment: Sorry, but if your users can add columns to your application's database, you have other problems. What you _could_ do is a "custom field junction table", where you have rows like `OriginalRowId - Name - Value`, but then you're developing a database-in-a-database (or [EAV](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios)), and that's a problem in itself. You better ask your users why they think they need this. You're not building the next Excel / Access.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with EF.

You could try with [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#execute-a-query-and-map-it-to-a-list-of-dynamic-objects).

> Execute a query and map it to a list of dynamic objects
>
> ```
> public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Query (this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, SqlTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true)
> ```
>
> This method will execute SQL and return a dynamic list.
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
>  var rows = connection.Query("select 1 A, 2 B union all select 3, 4");
>
>  Assert.Equal(1, (int)rows[0].A);
>  Assert.Equal(2, (int)rows[0].B);
>  Assert.Equal(3, (int)rows[1].A);
>  Assert.Equal(4, (int)rows[1].B);
> ```

## I still want it with EF

You could map data differently. Instead of new columns you could map the new data as a new value type in a related table and store values as rows, not columns.

This isn't ideal because you'd most likely end up storing the values as strings, but it could the job.

The table would look something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerDetails(
    [CustomerId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL
    (... setup keys, constraints, etc)
```

When the user creates a new column '`ColumnX`', the values for this column are stored as rows with `Name = 'ColumnX'`.